# How to close UI Kitten modal on back button press in android?

Tags: react-native, react-native-ui-kitten

I am using [modal for React Native UI kitten](https://akveo.github.io/react-native-ui-kitten/docs/components/modal/overview#modal).

But the problem is I did't find anything like [onRequestClose](https://akveo.github.io/react-native-ui-kitten/docs/components/modal/overview#modal) prop like the [React Native](https://reactnative.dev/) provides for the modal. Nothing mentioned on their [API](https://akveo.github.io/react-native-ui-kitten/docs/components/modal/api#modal) also.

So is there anything like I can close the modal on back button press?

Comment: You can set `visible` to false to hide the modal.

Comment: But how can I set the `visible` to false, when the back button is pressed?

Comment: You can detect the back button press using the `backhandler`. The documentation mentions how we can run a method when the user presses the back button https://reactnative.dev/docs/backhandler, you can set visibility here.

Comment: But the problem is,  It is Android-only. :(

Comment: I tried using `backHandler` in modal, but it will override the `backHandler` set previously in the screen.
After the modal is closed, when I press back button again the screen will still trigger close modal.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest react-native-modal which is easy to use and customize https://github.com/react-native-modal/react-native-modal

Comment: Sorry, but I want to use the UI Kitten modal, in order to get their theme chaning benefits.